# .less doesn't work on windows server?

Tags: css, windows, less

I have a site hosted by a windows server, I usually use a linux server and in my website I'm using .less instead of normal .css.
The problem now is on windows server when I load a page It cannot be found .less into my directory. The file is in It in the right position and if I rename into style.css and change the called to less it takes the css.
Is .less incompatibility on windows server? I never had this problem with .less
Why on windows server .less doesn't work? I have to change something in my code? I cannot change something in the server because isn't mine is a server on Aruba.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/styles.less" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the .less file extension to IIS.

Right-click your website and select properties, then HTTP Headers and add the MIME type.

Comment: I think that I can't change extension on IIS because is on Aruba server the host

Comment: You might need to get in touch with the Aruba support desk, then.

Comment: Their answer can be a lot of time and I want to put online my website in a few days, the support isn't quickly, I have tried with other thing and I have already to retrieve an answer

Comment: Take your compiled css (local) and add it to a css file which you then use online. You should do this anyways since the css will be compiled everytime a user loads the site (unless you cache it).

Comment: how to retrieve the compiled css in local?

Comment: As far as i know, just access the .less file in the browser and you will get the plain css. Otherwise you can use an online compiler like http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the less through a compiler such as winless, simpleless or crunch.